# Is there a way to turn this repeated code into a single, clean method

Tags: c#, function, linq, delegates, refactoring

I have the following code in my search logic which references a legacy database where the only way I can match the search is on the table row name, Level-1, Level-2 etc.

```
if (criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-1", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    var filteredResult = allCachedItems
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level1));

    resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
}

if (criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-2", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    var filteredResult = allCachedItems
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level2));

    resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
}

if (criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-3", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    var filteredResult = allCachedItems
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level3));

    resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
}
```

Obviously this looks horrible and is repeated code, so I would like to create a method which can accept a string, e.g. "Level-1" and some sort of delegate to determine which of the properties on the model to test against.

Or an otherwise cleaner way of approaching the filtering of my "allCachedItems" collection.

The table has a number of columns named Level{X} each contains some text where appropriate to the record and is empty where it is not appropriate.

The search form passes plain text in the format "Level-{x}".

Comment: Create a `Dictionary<string, Predicate<CacheItem>>` to get the mapping for every name/property. Then loop over criteria.Levels to concatenate those predicates with an "Or" and in the end execute `allCachedItems.Where` once with that predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a crack:

```
void AddCachedLevel(string level, Func<Item, string> property)
{
    if (criteria.Levels.Contains(level, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var filteredResult = allCachedItems.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(property(x)));
        resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
    }
}

AddCachedLevel("Level-1", x => x.Level1);
AddCachedLevel("Level-2", x => x.Level2);
AddCachedLevel("Level-3", x => x.Level3);
```

---

Or this, if `resultsSet` is initially empty:

```
List<Item> resultsSet =
(
    from x in allCachedItems
    where
        criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-1", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level1)
        || criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-2", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level2)
        || criteria.Levels.Contains("Level-3", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Level3)
    select x
).ToList();
```

---

Or this, if you want a combination of the two:

```
bool Check(Item item, string level, Func<Item, string> property) =>
    criteria.Levels.Contains(level, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(property(item));
    
List<Item> resultsSet =
(
    from item in allCachedItems
    where
        Check(item, "Level-1", x => x.Level1)
        || Check(item, "Level-2", x => x.Level2)
        || Check(item, "Level-3", x => x.Level3)
    select item
).ToList();
```

---

Or this for the ultimate slam down of repetition.

```
bool Check(Item item, string level, Func<Item, string> property) =>
    criteria.Levels.Contains(level, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(property(item));

Func<Item, bool>[] checks = new Func<Item, bool>[]
{
    i => Check(i, "Level-1", x => x.Level1),
    i => Check(i, "Level-2", x => x.Level2),
    i => Check(i, "Level-3", x => x.Level3),
};

List<Item> resultsSet =
(
    from item in allCachedItems
    where checks.Any(check => check(item))
    select item
).ToList();
```

Comment: Option one is exactly what I was looking for, nice, simple and easy to read when I come back to it in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> so I would like to create a method which can accept a string, e.g. "Level-1" and some sort of delegate to determine which of the properties on the model to test against.

You can create a local function like this:

```
void AddLevelToResultSet(int level, Func<X, string?> levelProperty) {
    // kind of weird that you are using a culture-specific comparison here...
    if (criteria.Levels.Contains($"Level-{level}", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var filteredResult = allCachedItems
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(levelProperty(x)));
    
        resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
    }
}

// ...

AddLevelToResultSet(1, x => x.Level1);
AddLevelToResultSet(2, x => x.Level2);
AddLevelToResultSet(3, x => x.Level3);
```

where `X` is the type of items in `allCachedItems`.

Also consider using a `Dictionary<int, Func<X, string?>>` to record the mapping between levels and properties:

```
Dictionary<int, Func<X, string?>> mapping = new() {
    { 1, x => x.Level1 },
    { 2, x => x.Level2 },
    { 3, x => x.Level3 },
}
```

This way, `AddLevelToResultSet` just needs the `level` parameter. `levelProperty` can be computed with `mapping[level]`.

> Or an otherwise cleaner way of approaching the filtering of my `allCachedItems` collection.

If `allCachedItems` is an ordinary collection (as opposed to, e.g. `IQueryable`), and also that all the levels are disjoint, you can do this in a single `Where`, where all the levels are connected with `||`.

```
// local helper function
bool CheckForLevel(int level, X item) =>
    criteria.Levels.Contains(
        $"Level-{level}", 
        StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
    ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mapping[level](item));

var filteredResult = allCachedItems
    .Where(x => 
        CheckForLevel(1, x) || 
        CheckForLevel(2, x) || 
        CheckForLevel(3, x)
    );
resultsSet.AddRange(filteredResult.Except(resultsSet));
```

Comment: Thank you for putting together this answer, I appreciate the response.